# Will Nagorno-Karabakh put my entry/exits stamps on a separate piece of paper?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps, azerbaijan, disputed-territories, nagorno-karabakh

Certain countries won't let a visitor enter if they have a passport stamp from certain other countries.

One case is Azerbaijan which will not permit you to enter if you have a stamp of Nagorno-Karabakh.

In some parts of the world with problems like this the place with the controversial stamp may put it on a separate piece of paper rather than in your passport. Reportedly Cuba will do this for Americans for instance.

Does anybody know whether Nagorno-Karabakh will do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes this is possible 100%. I just came back from a visit to Armenia and Nagorno Karabagh. The visa agent at Nagorno Karabagh will ask you if you want to have the visa on a separate paper. This is very common since most foreign visitors will prefer it this way. That was my experience. If one agent forgets to ask just ask it yourself, they are willing to do it.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think its possible. When we went there last year they insisted on placing a full-page sticker visa into our passports. You might be lucky, but I don't think there is an official way to get it done.

Comment: You mean a full page visa for Nagorno-Karabakh and not just the full page one for Armenia like I had?

Comment: Yeah, I just checked and I have two separate visas.

Comment: Hmm I'm running low on blank pages in my passport so it looks like I have two issues rather than just one!

Comment: @hippietrail: The solution might be quite easy to both of the problems then, just order a new passport after visiting?

Comment: As long as he is not going to Azerbaijan straight after of course :)

Comment: Ha well I would only get a temporary passport while I'm away from Australia and they're only valid for six months and most places have a stipulation of six months minimum passport validity for you to enter...

Comment: Sorry to unaccept but I've now also received the exact opposite answer \-:

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to get a second passport from your Government. Some, like the UK, do this due to this problem.

Comment: That's a good idea, but not very helpful if you are already away from your home country and have no way to secure a second passport (we all know it takes ages to get a new one from an embassy).

Comment: @mindcorrosive contact your embassy and find out? Sometimes they might be helpful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I checked this when it was mentioned on another question and found that Australia doesn't do this. I better check again and come up with a link though.

Comment: @mindcorrosive Well, that would also depend on the country. I recently got a passport in a little more than a week from my consulate. I could also ask for a second passport if I wanted to go to incompatible countries. Seems Australia is less accommodating on both counts however.